# How to remove these unneeded permissions

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I'm building project with android-studio gradle build system. I have two of below permissions

```
android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE
android.permission.INTERNET
```

but build system adds these new permissions automatically.

```
android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE maxSdkVersion=18
android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE
android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE maxSdkVersion=18
```

I don't understand why these permissions added. And how to remove these permissions?

Here is my build config

build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 20
    buildToolsVersion "20.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "my.app.package.name"
        minSdkVersion 8
        targetSdkVersion 20
        versionCode 2
        versionName "1.0.1"
    }
    signingConfigs {
        debug {
            storeFile file(System.getProperty("user.home")+"/.android/debug.keystore")
        }

        release {
            storeFile file("keystore.jks")
            storePassword "password"
            keyAlias "alias"
            keyPassword "password"
       }
    }
    buildTypes {
        /*release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }*/
        marketShareRelease {
            debuggable false
            jniDebuggable false
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:20.0.0'
    compile 'com.viewpagerindicator:library:2.4.1'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4'
    compile 'com.commonsware.cwac:merge:1.0.2'
}
```

My previous build almost same (on October 8, 2014). Simply Android studio and sdk are updated [image: play store reported new permissions added]

Comment: Just a shot in the dark here, but are you, by chance accessing files on the sdcard? That's what the permissions are for mostly. Perhaps you added code that reads/writes to SD, and your IDE added the needed permissions for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of your libraries has a targetSdk <= 4. (Looks like your cwac-merge)

This causes the permissions to be auto added: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#READ_PHONE_STATE